# PHP interval calculation issue with Chronos

Tags: php, date, php-chronos

Any help would be amazing since I can't figure it out.

At the moment I have a date time object (eg. '2017-01-05 23:22:27') and a user selected repeat interval (every 2 days between Monday(1) and Friday(5) for example) I can get the current day of the week from the datetime with

`$dayOfWeek = date("w", time($dateObject->timestamp));`

But I have no idea to check that it's within the weekdays and if it's outside how to calculate the extra days for it to be within the interval again and add this to the date.

For example, if Wednesday is the 4th, after running it through this then it would need to return with the datetime on the 6th, after running this through again, it would need to return the 9th as this is the next day that is inside the weekday interval.

I'm using CakePHP 3 and Chronos if that's of any help.

Comment: There is only 1 day *between* Tuesday and Thursday.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that, a better example would be every 2 days between Monday (1) and Friday (5), so the event would need to occur on Monday, Wednesday and Friday

Comment: Given the code above, what is missing, is the end date.  But assume the end date is said friday, you could do a loop, adding `$tmpDate = date($dateObject->timestamp, '+2 day');` then check `$tmpDate` if it is `>=` weekday start and `<=` weekday end, and alse check if it is between the start date and end date from wherever you have those values stored. Steves solution is if you are looking for the string representation of the day from the integer representation of the day of week.

Comment: Have you had a look at [**the Chronos docs**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html) (**[API](https://api.cakephp.org/chronos/1.0/)**)? It has a lot of methods that help you with comparison, extraction, intervals, etc...

Comment: Yes, I've been through that page about 5 times now to no success, there's nothing really there for weekday comparison, just the date in general, I'm just trying out kraang prime's solution

Comment: @B1scuit - let me know if you need me to whip up an example.  The loop can be customized to be inclusive of start and end dates or strict on every 2 days between regardless of end date landing on an 'off' day.

Comment: I popped in your solution and with a bit of adjustment it's now working, thank you, if at all possible can you put your solution as an answer so I can mark the issue as solved?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `date("w", time($dateObject->timestamp))` you can use `date('l',...)` for the shortened day of the week (i.e. Mon, Tue, etc.) or you can use `date('d',...)` for the full name (i.e. Monday, Tuesday, etc.).

If you're assigning a numeric value to each day, use an array to store each:

```
$days = array(0 => 'Sunday', 1 => 'Monday', 2 => 'Tuesday', 3 => 'Wednesday', 4 => 'Thursday', 5 => 'Friday', 6 => 'Saturday');
```

If you decide to use the short name in the above `date()` function, just replace the full day of the week in the `$days` array with the three-letter name instead.

Since you're using a numeric mapping for days of the week, you can then use 0-6 in conditional (`if/else`) statements to determine if it's in the interval or not.

Here's the PHP.net documentation on the `date()` function along with character formatting: [PHP.net date() Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)